# Where is Turkish's boxing office?

Tags: snatch

In the year 2000 film Snatch, lead character Turkish keeps an office in an old crumbling Caravan (Travel Trailer), in establishing shots of exterior around the caravan we see a character (Charlie) cooking sausages on a flaming BBQ grill, and we see boxer Gorgeous George training with a punching bag. Turkish and his partner Tommy discuss the need to buy a better Caravan, which is central to the plot.

The entire area is somewhat dark and seems to have at least one or two walls, implying it may be indoors, however a Caravan would typically be needed for an office if you were outdoors, and one wouldn't usually cook on a BBQ inside a building.

Where is this caravan / training facility located, is it outdoors but near an overpass or other building, giving it a somewhat indoor appearance? Is it in a warehouse or other large structure that might be big enough to make cooking with a BBQ feasible, but still warrant using a Caravan for an office?  Or is it at some other kind of place entirely?

Comment: I'm a simple man, I see the word "Snatch", I upvote.

Comment: I wonder if it was near the casino business they operated also. Maybe the back of the casino?

Comment: @NicholasAysen On one hand that could make sense, the wall in the shots of the caravan could be the back wall of the casino building, but on the other hand they have an indoor office in the back of the casino where Turkish keeps his safe, which seems like a more comfortable place to hang out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [script](https://www.dailyscript.com/scripts/snatch.pdf) refers to this place as "**Ext. Another Back Alley Makeshift Boxing Ring**" as opposed to Brick Top's "Ext. Back Alley Makeshift Boxing Ring". *Ext.* means exterior.

Turkish runs two businesses one is a slot machines house referred as "Amusement Arcade", the other is organizing unlicensed boxing matches and promoting his protégé Glorious George. This place is where Glorious George trains and stores boxing equipment and where they organize home matches and have barbecues (a boxer probably needs meat).

The exact place seems irrelevant to the plot, its purpose being to hold boxing and Glorious George related operations.

Comment: It doesn't quite 'feel' like an exterior location in the film, which is why I was curious. This is clearly the right answer, it's some annonymous gritty back alley where they are able to park the caravan, that just happens to have a bit of an interior vibe to it

Comment: @CameronRoberts indeed and it has to be private so they have their illegal fights without being disturbed by the cops. The backyard of the amusement arcade is a plausible option.